# How To Force Common Base Class Or Interface For Generated WCF ServiceReference Classes

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, soap

I'm writing a simple command line .NET application that retrieves data from a SOAP endpoint. I'm using WCF and Visual Studio 2017.

The SOAP service has about about 20 endpoints, each with its own WSDL. So far I was able to add a single working endpoint by adding a Service Reference in VS 2017. When I go to the Service Reference dialog, and add the WSDL for the endpoint, VS helpfully generates a Reference.cs with implementation for an Interface, Client, Collection, and Record. So far so good. As long as we're only dealing with a single endpoint.

The problem is that, now all of this auto-generated code is blown out, I need to write some semi-generic code to iterate through and call each of these endpoints. Clearly there's got to be some way to call client.process(requestMessage) without explicitly handling 20+ types.

The problem is that none of these generated classes have any sort of common base class or interface. For example, VS generates client, collection, and record classes for SuperDuperService:

```
superDuperInterfaceClient
responseMessageSuperDuperCollection
responseMessageSuperDuperCollectionSuperDuperRecord
```

The signatures for the above types are:

```
public partial class superDuperInterfaceClient : System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<the_project.SuperDuperService.superDuperInterface>, the_project.SuperDuperService.superDuperInterface {

public partial class superDuperCollection : object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {

public partial class responseMessageSuperDuperCollectionSuperDuperRecord : object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {
```

So... what gives? I'm sure I'm missing something completely obvious, but haven't been able to find anything that addresses what you'd think would be pretty straightforward. Apologies in advance most of my exposure to the .NET and C# world has been pretty ad hoc. Thanks!

Comment: Typically most services should share some basic classes if well designed, however a lot of people don't do top down WSDL development which leads to the code blow out you are seeing. Since the code needs to be generated from the WSDL you are at the mercy of the service provider in a proper design.

Comment: @Namphibian, that's about the size of it. Pretty sad that the only answer to the problem here is "Pray for better neighbors" though.

Comment: Not better neighbours informed and educated software engineers. The lack of discipline in the development arena is getting epic.

Comment: @Namphibian, I'm curious: Have you ever had to write client code to integrate against poorly designed systems that were not directly under your control? If not, enjoy it.

Comment: I have plenty. My hair loss can prove it too. I always try create my systems as if a homicidal maniac was going to interact with it. A little discipline makes a bit difference. So I have done it more than I would like to remember. There are no perfect systems I have no illusions about this.  Being in the integration space I encounter a lot of different systems. The question above really looks like a badly designed system i.e. base classes not properly defined in the XSD etc. I wish I could give you a better answer but without the WSDL and XSD's it is a guess.